# How can i run code in SAS Base from Atom Code Editor

Tags: sas, atom-editor

I use Atom Code Editor with the SAS package and would like to execute code directly from Atom passing the code to my SAS Base session (not opening a new session). I'd like to be able to execute a block of code that I select, not an entire file. Is there a way?

Comment: Do you want Atom to submit the actively edited file ?  Do you want to submit a selected block of text ?

Answer (score 0):

When you install SAS Foundation, it will add a context menu item "Submit with SAS" to Microsoft Windows Explorer.  The option performs this action: *Opens the program file in the Program Editor, and runs it. Output appears in regular SAS windows.*

The menu item causes these actions by executing the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\core\sasexe\sasoact.exe"
 action=Submit 
 datatype=SASFile 
 filename="%1"
```

If you can coerce Atom to submit that command line it should work.

Per paper ["Double-Clicking a SAS® File: What Happens Next?" Sandy Gibbs, Michele Mosca, and Donna Bennett, SAS Institute Inc.](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/115-2013.pdf)

> `sasoact` is used to launch an OLE automation session of SAS.

Comment: Thank you but this will open a new session and I'd like to run the code in my currently open session. Plus I'd like to be able to execute a block of code and not only an entire file

Comment: The command line in my answer has been corrected.  The initial answer had incorrect  options due to copy and pasting.  The incorrect options were `action=Print` instead of `action=Submit` and `type=New` instead of leaving off `type=`.  The `=New` setting value will cause `sasoact.exe` to always open and control a new SAS session, instead of controlling an existing active SAS session.